# Chaining promises returned from a generator function

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to chain the promises returned by a generator function.

I am expecting this to print:

```
started...
result is: initial value
result is: waited for 10ms
result is: waited for 20ms
done
```

But it prints:

```
started...
result is: initial value
undefined
result is: waited for 10ms
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const wait = async(ms) => 
    await new Promise((resolve) => 
        setTimeout((result = `waited for ${ms}ms`)=>resolve(result),ms))

const iterator = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield wait(10)
        yield wait(20)
    }
}

function chain(i) {
    return [...i].reduce((acc,c) => 
        acc.then((result) => 
            (console.log(`result is: ${result}`), c)), Promise.resolve('initial value'))
}

chain(iterator).then(() => console.log('done'))
console.log('started...')
```

Comment: You are using `Promise.then` to print the output and therefore missing the last result. Add this to your code and you will see the last line printed: `chain(iterator).then(console.log)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things is that your `console.log` was lagging by 1 element. So your iterations were like that:

1. Initial value resolves
2. Logs 'Initial value', 10ms resolves
3. Logs '10ms', 20ms resolves
4. Last `then`, gets '20ms' a result but doesn't log it, instead logs 'done'

You could see it in the next sample, that done part logs '20ms':

```js
const wait = async(ms) => 
    await new Promise((resolve) => 
        setTimeout(resolve,ms, `waited for ${ms}ms`))

const iterator = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield wait(10)
        yield wait(20)
    }
}

function chain(i) {
    return [...i].reduce((acc,c) => 
        acc.then((result) => (console.log(`result is: ${result}`), c)), Promise.resolve('initial value'))
}

chain(iterator).then((val) => console.log('done', val)) // <~ 20ms logs here
console.log('started...')
```

But wait, would you like to really `wait` sequentially for 10ms and then for 20ms, right? Because your current version isn't doing this. It just runs them in parallel, so probably you should do it in this way:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,ms, `waited for ${ms}ms`))

const iterator = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield wait(500)
        yield wait(1000)
    }
}

async function chain(i) {
    console.log('init')
    for (const promise of i) {
       const result = await promise
       console.log(`result is: ${result}`)
    }
}

chain(iterator).then(() => console.log('done'))
console.log('started...')
```

Hope it helps :)